# Pip install ultralytics throws ultralytics is not a valid editable requirement

Tags: virtualenv, python-module, modulenotfounderror

I am using a conda environment with Python 3.10.8.

As described on the github, I tried:

- `git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics`
- `pip install -qe ultralytics`

but that throws

> ERROR: ultralytics is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).

Answer (score 0):

-e argument specifies *editable mode* as you can see in pip documentation : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options

You can read in your error, this argument is the issue.

Just type :

```
pip install ultralytics
```

It should work.